# Solution to "could not find a declaration file for module 'socket.io-client'

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17BZK.jpg)

Wagwan people... I installed socket.io-client version 2.4.0 cause it is what i wanna make use of for this little project but i've been hit with this unfortunate error this early morning.. what should be done to fix this..
Thanks in advance peeps
All Love

Comment: Please add your code as text not images. Have you installed `socket.io-client`?

Comment: Yes i installed socket.io client but its an old version i installed